# why are (html) classes called .classname?

Tags: html, css, class

why are (html/css) classes called .classname?

Example:

Animated
Add .active to .progress-striped to animate the stripes right to left. Not available in all versions of IE.

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
<div class="bar" style="width: 40%;"></div>
</div>
```

I mean the "." part, why do they use a "." instead of just class?

Comment: `class` is reserved word in JS.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Because the spec says so? http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS files, a name with no prefix refers to a tag, a name with `#` prefix refers to an ID, and a name with `.` prefix refers to a class. The `.` is needed to distinguish class names from tag names.

Answer (score 1):

The following may or may not be applicable to the question. Take it or leave it.

---

The DOM *specifies* that `class` (the HTML attribute) is exposed as `className`. (Refer to [2.5.4. The HTMLElement interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html#ID-011100101).)

This was done so that common environments *cough* JavaScript *cough* can refer to the identifier bare-form.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is, but if you are having issues with CSS Chained classes not working your page may be running in quirks mode.  Try adding this at the very top of your webpage before your head tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```